# Why is Jester blue and Lillith white in Critical Role?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, tiefling, critical-role-show, exandria

I do not watch Critical Role and know very little about it.

However, whilst looking into different skin colours for tieflings, I discovered the characters Jester Lavorre, who has blue skin, and Lillith Daturai, who has white skin. I am curious to know what in-universe lore exists in Matt Mercer's homebrew universe to explain why these tiefling characters have the skin colour that they do. Searching online, I have been unable to find such information, simply that they are the colours that they are, not why.

I believe the *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount* book is out now, and I don't know if this is the sort of thing that would be in that book, but I don't know where else such lore might be found besides watching the show (or possibly statements by those involved in the show, such as Matt Mercer, etc). For reasons unrelated to this question/lore that I don't want to expand on, watching the show is not something I plan to do, but I'm still curious about the universe and the lore relating to these tieflings' skin colour.

So, from an in-universe lore perspective, why is Jester blue and Lillith white in the Critical Role homebrew universe?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105645/discussion-on-question-by-nathans-why-is-jester-blue-and-lillith-white-in-critic).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Jester's coloration is explained in the narrative.

Critical Role Spoilers:
Although Jester's mom is a (red-skinned) tiefling, her father is a

> water genasi.

This lends her the blue color, as well as the decidedly non-tiefling resistance to cold damage, instead of fire damage.

## Lillith is a bit less clear

No mention (to my knowledge) is made of Lillith's coloration.  It is possible that she is simply extremely pale, or has albinism.  The 5e player's handbook says that Tiefling coloration can be anything a human could have. Very pale or albino coloration is not out of the question.

As an aside, the world of Exandria, Matt Mercer's world, is quite a bit more varied, and less likely to be concerned about the lore or rules in many ways.  The goal of the stream/podcast is to tell a good story, and if a blue or white tiefling is part of a good story, then it'll get in there.  Similarly, Matt is often willing to bend the rules to allow something interesting or to add inclusivity to the world (see the blind shakaste, for example, who sees through a hummingbird familiar).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and I understand that the primary goal of the show is entertainment rather than "rules", but it's still good to know the in-universe explanation (the bit in spoiler quotes is exactly what I was after). +1

Comment: For the Jester part: that's a possible explanation, but stated as a fact here like it is would tend to imply this is more than a personal theory, but rather has some basis in canon. That should be clarified.

Comment: @T.E.D. Someone with lots of time could probably go through the "Talks Machina" after-show streams around when that all was revealed and find a reference.  I know they specifically mention the change to her resistance as being an inheritance, though I'm less confident they directly mention her coloration.

Are you implying that anything less explicit than Matt or Laura saying directly "Jester is blue because of her dad" makes it a personal theory?

Comment: @Tal - Well, that's all of us now that its on hiatus.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I'm pretty sure that has been stated about that directly by Laura or Matt, at some point on Talks, once the story reason was revealed.  I've watched every Talks episode and have a fairly good memory, and I *think* I remember this being actually confirmed by Laura that she'd discussed this with Matt as the reason why Jester was blue.  Also the reason she has cold resist and her Hellish Rebuke does cold damage. (Spoiler alert: I'm less sure that either of them has discussed the fact that it's not acid resistance like one might expect; I think that was just youtube comments.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - I watched all the talks as well, and have a really wretched memory, and don't remember that one at all. :-) So, there's a chance you're right, but I reiterate that it shouldn't be stated as if its a fact in a post with no reference whatsoever backing it up. Not-trivial assertions need to come with references.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Certainly, like I said I *think* I remember this, but I was only about 90 to 95% sure.  I had to disentangle it from my clearer memories of what Laura said about discussions with Matt about her warlock patron in the campaign wrap-up.  I checked the critrole wiki for [Jester](https://criticalrole.fandom.com/wiki/Jester_Lavorre): it cites TMx82 (discussing C2E34 where Marion confirmed her dad, with Laura and Matt as guests) as the source for her cold resist and rebuke damage being due to her parentage.  But without a timestamp.  I didn't look for a summary / recap of that TM ep.

Comment: @PeterCordes My answer provides timestamps and transcripts of all the relevant evidence for both Jester and Lillith.

Answer (score 23):

## Re: Lillith...

Hi folks! Kit here - Lillith's player. Super simple explanation for Lillith's white colouration: it's due to albinism. She's an albino tiefling :) Hope that clears it up!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Thanks for checking by and happy gaming.

Comment: Has this been mentioned as part of the show or in supplementary material? It's not that I don't believe you, but it would be very nice to have a verifiable source for this information.

Comment: Might it be mentioned in the [*Cloven: Bloodlines*](https://www.anemonetea.com/cloven-bloodlines-comic.html) 3-issue comic series? If so, a citation to the relevant bit (possibly with an image of the panel where it's mentioned, if you want) would definitely improve the answer. :) (Otherwise, I've seen it mentioned in others' fanart, some of which you've replied to, and referenced in one line of this Geek & Sundry article: [Critical Role Celebrity Playlist: Lillith’s Playlist By Kit Buss](https://geekandsundry.com/critical-role-celebrity-playlist-lilliths-playlist-by-kit-buss/).)

Comment: Also, if [this transcript of C1E25, "Crimson Diplomacy"](https://criticalrole.fandom.com/wiki/Crimson_Diplomacy/Transcript) is accurate, then Matt calls Lillith an albino tiefling once in that episode. Someone can find/share the timestamped video link to confirm. ...It's referenced again in [C1E91, "Vox Machina Go to Hell"](https://criticalrole.fandom.com/wiki/Vox_Machina_Go_to_Hell/Transcript): "MATT: You have encountered an albino tiefling before. [...] TALIESIN: Lillith. LAURA: Lillith was an albino? [...] That’s why she was so pale." (Thanks, Critical Role wiki's search function! :P)

Comment: It's a shame this only answers half the question, because I'd love to see it as the accepted answer simply for being "Word of God" on the other half of the question.

Comment: Additional support on the authenticity of this answer is Kit Buss's twitter https://twitter.com/AnemoneTea , which includes the line "Drawing comics about horned albino illusionists."

Comment: Thanks for the answer "from the source" @Someone_Evil I'll take Kit at their word.

Answer (score 12):

## It is not known

I don't know if there is any in-universe explanation in the show but I found something in the *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*'s section on [tieflings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/egtw/character-options#Tieflings) (emphasis mine):

> Exandrian tieflings have a wide array of skin tones, all of them vibrant and colorful. The most common hue is a deep crimson, but shades of purple, blue, green, and even yellow and pink have been seen throughout the world. **It’s not known what causes these variations**, as even tiefling parents with the same skin tone can have children of wildly different colors.

So it is not inherited and there is no further explanation where the color originates from. But at least this part states that there are blue-colored tieflings in this world.

There is also a part in the *Player's Handbook* and Basic Rules about [tieflings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/races#InfernalBloodline), but it also just states the different color variations and does not explain where they come from:

> Their skin tones cover the full range of human coloration, but also include various shades of red.

Comment: This answer is unfortunately incorrect. The reasons for both Jester's and Lillith's colorations are known.

Answer (score 12):

#### Jester was blue because....

> Her father, The Gentleman, is a water genasi.

The above relationship is well known, but as the cause for Jester's coloration and resistance to cold damage, Jester concludes that it is the reason for her color in episode 34, "Encroaching Waters":

> LAURA: (gasps) My dad is from islands! At least he was. Did you know my dad might be The Gentleman?
>
> ASHLEY: You mean–?
>
> TRAVIS: Yeah, that happened.
>
> SAM: The moist guy.
>
> ASHLEY: The guy that sweats all the time?
>
> TRAVIS: Has all our blood.
>
> *LAURA: (whispering) That’s why I’m blue!*
>
> ASHLEY: Jester!
>
> LAURA: I know!
>
> LIAM: It’s probable. It has not been verified.

While Liam (in character as Caleb) says it has not been verified, Matt and Laura would later confirm this on *Talks Machina* discussing the events of episode 34 ([timestamped youtube link](https://youtu.be/XdjbYE7UAsg?t=3497)):

> BRIAN: When coming up with this iteration of Jester, you modified some of her tiefling racial traits. Did you intend for these to be tied to jesters father when making Jester [...]?
>
>  [...]
>
>  LAURA: Before I had decided on Jester, I had thought about making a water genasi character. And, I was thinking of doing a water genasi warlock. Maybe she's got some of that in there and she just doesn't know it or something.
>
> MATT: We were at your house working on the specifics of Jester, and you were like "well is there like a possible crossover between the two bloodlines", and I was like "sure, it would change and adjust things a little bit." Skin tone would make sense, resistance wise, I like to think that it wouldn't be one or the other, it would kind of go in a different direction based on that shift. And so that's why she has cold resistance over fire resistance. [...] And the fact that when you do Hellish Rebuke it's cold damage as opposed to fire damage. So it's all just kind of this unique merging of those two bloodlines.

#### Lillith had albinism.

Kit Buss, Lillith's player, stated in [her answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/166573/62294) that Lillith had albinism. This was confirmed on stream by Matthew Mercer in episode 91 of campaign 1, "Vox Machina Go to Hell" at around the 1:50:11 mark ([youtube link](https://youtu.be/mymhgcNgqBY?t=01h050m011s), [episode transcript](https://crtranscript.tumblr.com/ep091)):

> MATT: You have encountered an albino tiefling
> before.
>
> TALIESIN: We have.
>
> MARISHA: Have we?
>
> LIAM: Smartypants.
>
> TALIESIN: Lillith.
>
> LAURA: Lillith was an albino?
>
> MARISHA: Lillith.
>
> LAURA: That’s why she was so pale.
>
> MARISHA: She was so cute!

Comment: Man goes in with a deep cut to get to the truth. Admirable. But, and I know that we'd be retreading ground on other answers, I think it would be wise to have a brief mention of Jester's coloration for this answer as well for completeness sake.

Comment: @GuidingOlive Fair enough, I'll see about getting a more specific quote from the stream for Jester.

Comment: @GuidingOlive Try it now.

Answer (score 6):

### There is a precedent for blue, and a stretch for white, neither with lore explanations

*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* (p. 118) mentions a [variant of tiefling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/races-of-the-realms#LoneFaithful) with dark blue-tinted skin:

> Rather than having the physical characteristics described in the
>   Player's Handbook, choose 1d4+1 following features: small horns; fangs
>   or sharp teeth; a forked tongue; catlike eyes; six fingers on each
>   hand; goatlike legs; cloven hoofs; a forked tail; leathery or scaly
>   skin; red or dark blue skin; cast no shadow or reflection; exude a
>   smell of brimstone.

But that seems to be the only 5e material that mentions a different skin color for tieflings and **no direct connection between their appearance and any in-universe explanation, though some parallels can be drawn between tiefling features and certain D&D creatures.**

SCAG explains Jester's blue color, but Lilith's is a bit more complicated. According to the 5e *Player's Handbook*'s section on [tieflings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/tiefling#InfernalBloodline) (p. 42):

> [Tiefling] skin tones cover the full range of human coloration, [...]

Which, in theory, can cover an extreme case of paleness, but a pure white Tiefling has no official precedent I know of. However, SCAG also mentions the Imaskari, a human variant with white, smooth skin, setting a precedent as part of the full range of human coloration.

Comment: This answer is unfortunately incorrect. The lore reasons for both Jester's and Lillith's colorations are known.